# How to split a large json file input into different elastic search index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

The input to logstash is

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/tmp/very-large.json"
        type => "json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
```

and sample json file

```
{"type":"type1", "msg":"..."}
{"type":"type2", "msg":"..."}
{"type":"type1", "msg":"..."}
{"type":"type3", "msg":"..."}
```

Is it possible to make them feed into different elastic search index, so I can process them easier in the future?

I know if it is possible to assign them with a `tag`, then I can do something like

```
if "type1" in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        action => "index"
        index => "logstash-type1%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        flush_size => 50
    }
}
```

How to do similar thing by looking at a specific json field value, e.g. `type` in my above example?

Comment: The answer is correct, but just for reference, you can do: if [type] == "type1"

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, just use the `type` field to build the index name like this:

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    action => "index"
    index => "logstash-%{type}%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    flush_size => 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare on any fields. You'll have to first parse your json with the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) or [codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html).

Then you'll have a `type` field to work on, like this:

```
if [type] == "type1" {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        index => "logstash-type1%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
} else if [type] == "type2" {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        index => "logstash-type2%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
} ...
```

Or like in Val's answer:

```
elasticsearch {  
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]  
    action => "index"  
    index => "logstash-%{type}%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"  
    flush_size => 50  
}
```